# Change GridView datatemplate and binding dynamically

Tags: c#, gridview, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a gridview which is filled with a List. The StreamCollection class has 2 properties, 1 of type Track, and one of type Playlist. I have a Datatemplate for the track model and one for the playlist model. Is it possible to dynamically change the gridview template, depending which kind of the StreamCollectionItem is set? Maybe with the use of a converter?

Example if Track is set but Playlist is null, then it'd change the binding and template for that specific item to track in the gridview. If Playlist is set and Track is null, it will show the Playlist binding and item.

Comment: You can use ItemTemplateSelector.

Comment: Is it also possible to set the binding for that specific element?

Comment: you have to  define two templates and bind it to respective templates

Comment: I managed to change the template (http://pastebin.com/VFAa2j46). But I also want to change that binding for that item. The templates already have predefined bindings (TrackDataTemplate has the Track model as binding, same for playlist). But now it has the StreamCollection as binding. Can I change the binding for that item to Track or Playlist then?

Comment: How does it have streamcollection binding. I guess gridview has streamcollection DataContext. Templates will be having track or playlist depending upon the templates